# Finding Relative Orbit number from Sentinel 1 image

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

```
python 
after = ee.Image(IC_post.sort('system:time_start').limit(1))
properties = after.getInfo()
properties['relativeOrbitNumber_start']
```

I am trying to find the relative orbit of a Sentinel 1 image from its metadata to filter an image collection to only that geometry.

I think that .getInfo() should return a dictionary of metadata and that the key ['relativeOrbitNumber_start'] should return the correct relative orbit but it just throws an error.

What am I messing up?

[image: .getInfo(), that contains what I want to get out[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtKfT.png)

Comment: Have you tried printing the properties? All of them to see if there actually is the one you are looking for?

Comment: I have and I included a screenshot above of the property I want to get out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `ee.Image` (or `ee.Feature`) property by invoking `get()`, `getNumber()`, or one of the other `get*()` functions.

```
var geometry = Map.getBounds(true)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01')
var image = collection.first()
var relativeOrbitNumber = image.getNumber('relativeOrbitNumber_start')
var filtered = collection.filterMetadata('relativeOrbitNumber_start', 'equals', relativeOrbitNumber)
print('relativeOrbitNumber', relativeOrbitNumber)
print('Images', collection.size())
print('Images with orbit number', filtered.size())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccb1e81dd6fa018766453a2a4061e49d

In general, try to avoid calling `getInfo()` unless you really, really need to.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the reply. I gave this a try and when I print off the relative orbit number it says ee.Number with lots of other information. I included a screenshot above. How can I get the number on its own out do I need to bring it to my client before I try to print it off? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you’re not in the code editor. Then you’ll need the getInfo() call within your print statement.